# Remove serie if condition is true chart

Tags: c#, winforms, bar-chart

I have a bar chart where I set LegendText like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < timeCount; i++)
{
    empChart.Series[employee].LegendText = $"{employee}: {formattedTime}";
}
```

So for each employee, it creates one LegendText. What I want to do is not display the LegendText if formattedTime equals to "0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes" so this is what I do:

```
if (formattedTime.Equals("0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes"))
{
    empChart.Series[employee].LegendText = string.Empty;
}
```

For some reason formatted time disappears, but employee does not. It is still appearing

```
empChart.Series[employee].LegendText = $"{employee}: {formattedTime}"
```

Why does it still appear as serie name? How can I remove serie name if my formattedTime equals to "0 Days 0 Hours 0 Minutes"? Regards

Note: I also tried with

```
empChart.Series[employee].Points.Clear();
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: You need to 'Hide' the LegendText and not just set it to empty string if that's what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, as comment above I need to hide LegendText. To do that just need to set `IsVisibleLegend` to false like:

```
 empChart.Series[employee].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
```